# JAVAFX FXML: dynamic ImageView in dynamically created tabs not displaying

Tags: image, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am making a java app that will display ski resort weather data. Upon user login it creates a scene that has a Tab Pane with dynamically created tabs, one for each of the users favorited resorts. All of the data is being stored in a mysql database.

I am able to successfully create all the the tabs for each user, now I am trying to load an image associated with each resort into each tab being loaded, using an ImageView object. I have no Idea why but I can not get any images to show up in any of the tabs. Ideally I want to take the name of the image file, that I have stored in my database, create a the file path string and load the image. I have also tried hardcoding the file path, and setting the image in scene builder but neither work.

My favorites controller that has the tabPane and dynamically creates tabs

```
@FXML
private TabPane tabPane;
private Tab myTab;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 * @param url
 * @param rb
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    try {
        DBConnect dbConnection = new DBConnect();
        // GET USER ID, THEN ARRAY OF THE ID'S FAVORITE RESORTS
        int id = LoggedInUser.id;
        //string array of the names of the users favorited resorts
        String[] resorts = dbConnection.getFavorites(id);

        // DYNAMICALLY CREATE TABS BASED ON THE NUMBER OF FAVORITES FOR THE ACTIVE USER.
        for(int i = 0; i < resorts.length; i++) {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            ResortTab newTabController = new ResortTab(resorts[i]);
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("ResortTab.fxml"));
            loader.setController(newTabController);

            Parent parent = loader.load();
            myTab = new Tab(resorts[i]);
            myTab.setContent(parent); 
            tabPane.getTabs().add(myTab);
        }

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FavoritesController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

ResortTab, controller for dynamically created tabs

```
public class ResortTab implements Initializable{
String name;
DBConnect dbConnection;
private Image image;
private String resort;


@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private ImageView logo;

// CONSTRUCTOR
public ResortTab(String name) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    resort = name;
    this.name = name;
    // GET LOGO FILE PATH FROM DATABASE AND LOAD IT TO THE SCENE
    dbConnection = new DBConnect();
    //returns file path thats stored in the database example: images/Logos/resortname.jpg
    String path = dbConnection.getLogoPath(name); 

    System.out.println("'src/jesnwdskiweather/" + path + "'");
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    // Create full path 
    String full_path = "file:'/src/jesnwdskiweather/" + path + "'";

    // String used to test by hardcoding
    String testPath = "file:'src/jesnwdskiweather/images/Logos/RevelstokeMountain.png'";

    System.out.println(full_path); //prints correct file path
    image = new Image(full_path);
    if(image == null){
        System.out.println("Image is null"); //does not print
    }

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    logo.setImage(image);
    logo.setCache(true);
    label.setText(name);
}
```

ResortTab.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
     <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="342.0" layoutY="112.0" text="Label" />
     <ImageView fx:id="logo" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: did you try 'setGraphic' method ?

Comment: Just tried that by putting a label in and doing, imageLabel.setGraphic(new ImageView(image)); in initialize() and the same thing happened.

Comment: There is no way `image` is `null` for an instance of `ResortTab`: Either the `Image` constructor returns a `Image` instance or it throws a exception. In none of those cases the `if`'s body is executed. Furthermore I'd expect the file url to be determined relative to the database url not relative to the source code directory. Furthermore the source directory will probably not be available in the release version and you should not make assumptions about the working directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to copy your code and make some changes to find ther error and i find that your error is here `String full_path = "file:'/src/jesnwdskiweather/" + path + "'";` and you don't need adding `/src/` to your path see the description

**False path :**

[image: here]

**True path :**
[image]

Try change the full path to  `String full_path = "jesnwdskiweather/" + path";`

Source code with some changes :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackoverflow;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Electron
 */
public class ResortTab implements Initializable {

    String name;
    private Image image;
    private String resort;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private ImageView logo;

// CONSTRUCTOR
    public ResortTab(String name) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        resort = name;
        this.name = name;
        // GET LOGO FILE PATH FROM DATABASE AND LOAD IT TO THE SCENE
      //  dbConnection = new DBConnect();
        //returns file path thats stored in the database example: images/Logos/resortname.jpg
        String path = "1487868084_39_Email_Marketing.png";

        System.out.println("'src/jesnwdskiweather/" + path + "'");
        System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        // Create full path 
        String full_path = "jesnwdskiweather/" + path +"";

        // String used to test by hardcoding
        String testPath = "file:'src/jesnwdskiweather/images/Logos/RevelstokeMountain.png'";

        System.out.println(full_path); //prints correct file path
        image = new Image(full_path);
        if (image == null) {
            System.out.println("Image is null"); //does not print
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        logo.setImage(image);
        logo.setCache(true);
        label.setText(name);
    }
}
```

**Note :** Your code add an image into each content of tab note into tab ,if you need to add an image into each tab use `setGraphic(node);`.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you this has had me stumped for quite a bit, I appreciate the help.